# Proving orthogonal complement only contains 0 vector

Tags: vector-spaces

Given the functions $v_n (x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}e^{i \pi n x}$, $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, I am to consider the orthogonal complement in $L^2 ([-a,a])$ of the vector space $V$ linearly generated by the ${v_n}$, i.e. the space $V^\perp = \{  f \in L^2 ([-a,a]) | <g,f>_2 = 0 \, \, \, \forall g \in V\}$. Also $0 < a < 1$.

I need to prove that $V^\perp$ only contains the null vector.

So I need some help understanding that one. First I'm assuming $L^2$ is a [function space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space). Now what does it mean exactly that $V$ is linearly generated by the ${v_n}$? Just that the elements of $V$ are built as linear combinations of the $v_n$ functions?

I don't really know where to go from there. Is there a theorem/result that may help me show that V contains only the 0 function? (if that's what the null vector is). any hint/explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes $V$ being linearly generated means that its elements are linear combinations of $v_n$. You may want to see Stein and Weiss. They prove this for the Fourier transform (but the proof is *very* similar for Fourier series - which is what you have here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that $V$ is  linearly-generated by the $v_n$ means that the $v_n$ are a basis. In particular, you can check that this is an orthonormal basis ( check that the $L^2$ inner-product of any two $v_i, v_j; i\neq j$ is 0 , and $<v_i, v_i>=1$ ). Orthonormal bases have the nice property that, while every vector $w$ in the space can be written as:

$\Sigma_{i=1} ^{\infty} c_nv_n$

And, while an expansion of this type holds for any basis, we have

a  nice general form for the coefficients  $c_n$ of any vector $w$:
We have that $c_n=<w, v_n>$

Now, let $w$ be any vector in $V^{\perp}$. Write this $w$ in terms of the basis $v_n$, and see what you get ( see what the $c_n$ are for $w$ ).

Comment: ok will try that and get back to you, thanks. also can you confirm that the null vector in this case if the constant function u(x)=0?

also when you write $c_n=<e_n, v_n>$, the $e_n$ are the basis vectors, correct?

Comment: Yes, Ethan, this is correct.

Comment: Didn't you mean rather that $c_n = < w , v_n >?$ That would make more sense since by "dotting" $w$ with the nth basis set vector we would pick out the corresponding $c_n$ while killing off the other components because of orthogonality. Just correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Ethan: yes, that's what I meant, sorry. Let me edit.